# nvidia driver: pantheon doesn't launch after apt upgrade

Tags: release-loki, updates, nvidia

I've updated 2 times few hours ago and now pantheon doesn't start. GRUB loads, linux actually boots, but the screen remains black. I can ctrl+alt+F1 into tty1, login and do stuff, but when I switch to tty7, the screen freezes. Tried restarting lightdm but that was useless.

The upgrades installed kernel 4.something.78 and a bunch of pantheon updates along with new icon pack. Appcenter icon changed to look like a house. I also check for upgrades every day, so, now I hope you understand approximately what upgrades I'm talking about. It's May 17th upgrades.

The PC is a notebook MSI GE60 20E. I also tried booting with previous version of the kernel, but the result is the same.

As it turned out, nvidia-381 drivers started conflict with something after update. I uninstalled them and now the desktop launches. But can someone explain what's happening and is it possible currently to run the latest updates with nvidia drivers? Also I don't want to install previous versions of nvidia drivers because they lacked prime settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what happened. Reinstalled the system, apt upgrade again, now it works.

**UPDATE**

I've just ran into the very same problem on the newly installed system. That happened after I installed some packages. Excluding one after another, I found that it's **nvidia-381**. I uninstalled it via tty1 and now it boots as it should. To clarify, these nvidia drivers worked well before those system updates.

**UPDATE**

I've just figured out how to preserve nvidia driver and boot. I think this could be a bug somewhere in that version of the driver, that X server doesn't start because that happened before. However, I'm inclined to think the bug is somewhere else. It used to work without any problems. But here's what you can do:

1. Log in to another tty: for example, ctrl+alt+F1
2. `sudo prime-select intel`
3. `sudo service lightdm restart`

Done.