# pantheon haveing problems after upgrade

Tags: updates

I update my system every day if there are updates. The last update was the one that changed the app center icon. There was also two drivers for intel and nvidia listed in the installed list, but they were not, I install both.

Now the system boots. The log-in screen is there, but when you log-in the display has black areas overtime the display my show the top menu, but it does not work. Them most of the time it kicks the system back to the log-in screen.
Not sure but I think it is the drivers, but I do not know how to remove them by hand.

Comment: Does a guest session work? If it is, it might be some user-level setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same problem as I had. look at my [question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11961/nvidia-driver-pantheon-doesnt-launch-after-apt-upgrade)

Here's what you should do:

1. Boot up the system, wait until that black screen. You may have to
   wait after that a little more, while it tries to launch graphical
   desktop.
2. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and you'll be switched to tty1: a console
   without graphical environment. There you be able to should log in. It may fail for the first few times. If so just try several times more.
3. Then you remove everything nvidia related. Run `sudo apt purge *nvidia*`
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you need a working nvidia driver and still want to be able to login do the following in the terminal

write

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers to add the repository
sudo apt-get update to activate the ability to use the above repository as it updates your reposity list

then use sudo apt-get install nvidia-387 to get the latest stable nvidia driver.

If it still doesnt work follow the above users respons to remove it once again